# How to disable Fast boot when BIOS is inaccessible

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios

I have legacy boot in my HDD, and after I enabled fast boot, my keyboard gets disabled during boot so i cannot access my BIOS setting. Is there a way I can maybe disable it(fastboot) without accessing BIOS.

Comment: If desktop PC, try removing CMOS battery (and wait for 5 minutes before you reinsert) or short the CLR_CMOS or CLR_CLK or similar pins on the board to reset BIOS to system defaults and see if that helps. If laptop see if removing battery and long press power button for 30 seconds when there's no power helps to get access to BIOS, upon subsequent boot. What if you just restart from within Ubuntu?

Comment: @patkim i tried restarting within ubuntu `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`  it returned `Cannot indicate to EFI to boot into setup mode: Firmware does not support boot into firmware.`